# imprimir variable con comillas en otro archivo php

Tags: php, mysql

Amigos que tal, tengo un problema con las "... realmente un dolor de cabeza. Tengo un php que escribe otro codigo php. Algo mas o menos asi:
Php1 escribe contenido en un archivo que se llama archivo y archivo debe ejecutar una sentencia mysql con el valor de una variable que se encontraba en php 1

```
<?php
$subs_nombre = "Junio";
$miArchivo = fopen("archivo.php", "w");
$php='<?php 
consulta1 = "select cp_id from config_camp where cp_nombre = "'.$subs_nombre.'" ";
$consulta1 = mysql_query($consulta1, $link);
?>';                                                                                                                                              


fwrite($miArchivo, $php);                                                                                                                         
fclose($miArchivo); 
?>
```

El problema es que PHP 2 se escribe asi

```
<?php
consulta1 = "select cp_id from config_camp where cp_nombre = "Junio" ";
$consulta1 = mysql_query($consulta1, $link);
?>
```

Y al estar asi al ejecutar "archivo.php", php me dice que no es posible puesto que tiene ". Entonces deberia ir con comillas simples ', pero no logro hacer que Junio quede como 'Junio'.

Alguien me puede dar una mano?

Comment: Haz intentado escapar las comillas con \' ?

Comment: Asi es, pero al escapar con \' lo que me aparece en el archivo creado (archivo.php) es 

 consulta1 = "select cp_id from config_camp where cp_nombre = "$subs_nombre" "; 

y esa variable solo existe en php1

Comment: Me parece muyyyy extraño que tengas manipular código de esta manera. ¿Se debe a algún motivo particular? No parece una manera ni cómoda ni segura de *programar*, o de organizar el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es escapar las comillas simples entre las cuales va a estar el valor de la variable `$subs_nombre`, para escapar dichas comillas basta con colocar un slash invertido `\` antes de cada una, así:

```
<?php
$subs_nombre = "Junio";
$miArchivo = fopen("archivo2.php", "w");
$php='<?php 
consulta1 = "select cp_id from config_camp where cp_nombre = \''.$subs_nombre.'\'";
$consulta1 = mysql_query($consulta1, $link);
?>';                                                                                                                                              


fwrite($miArchivo, $php);                                                                                                                         
fclose($miArchivo); 
?>
```

Logrando una salida válida

```
<?php 
consulta1 = "select cp_id from config_camp where cp_nombre = 'Junio'";
$consulta1 = mysql_query($consulta1, $link);
?>
```

Comment: gracias ! me soluciono el problema, estaba intentando escapar las comillas pero con comillas dobles ! gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Siempre al utilizar comillas dobles y adentro necesitar comillas de nuevo se deben usar las simples, tambien aplica al contrario en la mayoria de lenguajes,

ejemplo sencillo

```
echo "<div class='row'>";
```

o de otra manera

```
echo '<div class="row">';
```

Comment: lo tengo claro, el problema no es ese . El problema
es que en el archivo 1 debo obtener el contenido de la variable para que en php 2 la sentencia mysql quede con dicho contenido entre comillas simples y asi poder hacer la consulta

Comment: @Lusagsilva la respuesta de abajo no te solucionó el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto.

```
$ArcivoPhp = <<<Query
   <?php
      echo "hola mundo";
   ?>
Query;

echo $ArchivoPhp;
```

Comment: Esto marcaría error =-\ !, debes agregar explicación de lo que realiza el código. Revisar [ask].